# If else condition on radio buttons

Tags: winforms

I was able to create buttons.I will be using about 65 buttons, how do you use if else condition on the buttons? Can someone please show me an example? Thank you in advance.

```
    private void createButtons()
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        for(int i = 0;i <10;i++)
        {
            RadioButton b = new RadioButton();
            b.Name = i.ToString();
            b.Text = "radiobutton" + i.ToString();
            b.AutoSize = true;
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);

        }
    }
```

Comment: "how do you use if else condition on the buttons" you're going to have to elaborate.

Comment: I am a beginner. When I drag and drop a button on the form each button has its own name i.e radionbutton1 radiobutton2 etc. When you create buttons dynamically I dont know which is button1 or button2. With the example above how I can say "if radiobutton1.checked do this"? etc.

Comment: How about putting the RadioButtons in a list or an array? So you could use `if (allRadioButtons[1].checked) do this`

Comment: @Dominique1256 I do not recall the correct syntax for this. But when your method is called, I assume you can get the component which was the agent pressed, to fire the method call. By this you then can see if the agent is checked, if that is what you want.

Comment: @Andrea, could you please show me an example so that I can build up on that. I know how to use a list....list.Add from a class and its object. If tried doing "List<RadioButton> rb = new List<RadioButton>();

Comment: I pressed the enter button for a new line and it published it. What I was trying to say is when a use list.Add....what do I Add?

Comment: The _b_ created in your loop above

Comment: I still don't get it. I need to see an example. Do I have to create a new instance for every single buttons?  RadionButton b1, radioButton b2 etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting the RadioButtons in a list or an array? This way you could use `if (allRadioButtons[1].checked) {...}`.

Here is an example

```
    private List<RadioButton> allRadioButtons = new List<RadioButton>();

    private void createButtons()
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            RadioButton b = new RadioButton();
            b.Name = i.ToString();
            b.Text = "radiobutton" + i.ToString();
            b.AutoSize = true;
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
            //add every button to the list
            //the one with the Text radiobutton0 will be accessible as allRadioButtons[0]
            //the one with the Text radiobutton1: allRadioButtons[1]
            //etc
            allRadioButtons.Add(b);
        }

    }

    //you can use your list in any other method
    private void myMethod() {
        if (allRadioButtons[0].Checked)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Andrea. Now I understand. Up to now I have used lists to call the class properties, string, int. Now with this example I can see and understand the logic. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dominique1256 -- If you like Andrea's answer, you should accept it and also consider up-voting it as well.

Comment: Why is everything so hard at first:) how do you vote, how do I mark it as a solution? I clicked on the vote tab and nothing happened. It would be so much easier for new people like me to show "if you want to vote and accept it click here".

Comment: @Dominique1256 The reason you cannot vote is that you only have 4 reputation. Voting up requires 15 rep. Don't worry, you are going to gain it soon! [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is a little help.

Comment: @Dominique1256 Accepting an answer doesn't have a reputation limit but can only be done 15 minutes after asking the question. You can accept it now. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is even more information.

Answer (score 0):

If Andrea's answer didn't work for you (since you didn't mark it as a solution), another option would be to create a container, such as a `GroupBox`, and then add your programatically created `RadioButton` controls to this container. Then you can loop over the controls belonging to the `GroupBox` like this:

```
foreach (Control c in myGroupBox.Controls)
{
    if ((RadioButton)c).Checked)
        //Do something
}
```

This will loop over all the controls in the `GroupBox` and cast them to a `RadioButton` and check if they're checked or not. I've used something similar to this as the basis for quite a few requirements in different applications; it's very easy to make a recursive method that takes a `ControlCollection`, loop over it and apply logic as needed depending on some condition, like the type of control or perhaps the `Tag` value of the control.

Then as far as adding the `RadioButton`s to the `GroupBox` at run time you just do something like `myGroupBox.Controls.Add(b)` where `b` is the `RadioButton` you've created in your `for` loop in your sample code. [More on runtime control creation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82785s1h(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Now that I got 65 radiobuttons dynamically on the panel, the radio buttons are not perfectly line up. If I was using ASP.net I'd know how to do that with CSS, how do we do that in winform?

Comment: You can set their `Location` property when you create it. Figure it out what the height of a `RadioButton` is then add a few pixels for padding so they're all spaced evenly.

Comment: I am a beginner at winform so if I don't see an example it's hard for me to just implement your suggestion. Someone earlier was telling not to use 65 radiobuttons on the designer but it works just fine and all the radiobuttons are perfectly lined up. If there a down side by using the designer this way?. Thank you.